# Axios CORS error (403) even server allow all

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, axios

I tried to get the jwt token from the Springboot server with Axios POST request, and I got this error below:

```
xhr.js:166 OPTIONS url net::ERR_ABORTED 403
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It seems like it couldn't pass the preflight request with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. So I configured the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the header but somehow it is still not working.

Here is the code:

**React:**

```
return Axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'url',
      data: qs.stringify(json),
      headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'authorization': 'Basic token',
      },
    });
```

**Spring Boot:**

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration conf = new CorsConfiguration();
        conf.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        conf.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT"));
        conf.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept,Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        conf.setAllowCredentials(true);
        conf.setMaxAge(3600L);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I think your server is configured wrong. the client has nothing to do in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue. What I couldn't notice is that response header from the server doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. so **Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response has to tell browsers to allow any request from certain origin** (in this case http://localhost:3000) which I haven't set up to return by now. so I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` on the response header by using filter.

This is the code I added.

```
package com.citus.travelmaker.api.config.datasource;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {
    public SimpleCorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

The above code I got from [here](https://medium.com/@muiruri/spring-oauth2-and-cors-configuration-3529337525b4). With that I was able to get 200 status from the server.

You can also check out the difference of the response header between before and after I changed the code

#### Before

[image: ![](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/2dbc7988-fa6a-4c32-bcd0-ac71c67a0805/Untitled.png)]

#### After

[image]

As you can see, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` added nicely

Answer (score 1):

Try this, by default allow all headers and Urls just to check

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
}
```

Also shouldn't your url be without quote

```
return Axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: url,  // like this
  data: qs.stringify(json),
  headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'authorization': 'Basic token',
  },
});
```

Finally just to make a note

Check if your URL is permitted in security configuration else you will get 403

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
     ...
     .antMatchers("/url*").permitAll()  // Allow whatever url is passed
     ...
     ;
}
```